# Tab Bars with items of different sizes

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, customization, uitabbar

I'm building a tab bar where each tab bar item has a different size. Is there a way to subclass a UITabBar ? I read the documentation and it seems that UITabBars always UITabBarItems with the same size.

Can anyone confirm this ? What would be the neatest implementation of a custom UITabBar ?

Comment: Here is some links that might help. [Changing font size of tabbaritem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576592/changing-font-size-of-tabbaritem) and [TabbarItem size and position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729405/tabbaritem-size-and-position). The key is using `setTitleTextAttributes`

Comment: Got another [link](http://www.rumex.it/2010/07/how-to-customise-the-tab-bar-uitabbar-in-an-iphone-application-part-1-of-2/). It is an illustrated tutorial.

Comment: By the way, users might feel weird about UITabBar with items of different sizes.

Comment: It never changes the actual UITabBarItem's. Only their content